# Keras model tensorflow lite conversion input shape

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to convert my simple Keras model frozen graph to tensorflowlite but I'm not sure what the input shape is.

```
    toco 
--input_file='my_model.pb'
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/tmp/my_model.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=input_tensor \
--output_arrays=output_tensor \
--input_shapes=0,4,2851
```

My model is:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, activation="tanh", input_dim=4, kernel_initializer="random_uniform", name="input_tensor"))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear", kernel_initializer='random_uniform', name="output_tensor"))
```

Comment: `input_dim=4` means that each sample has a shape of `(4,)`, i.e. is a vector of length 4.

Comment: I tried putting: input_shapes=1,4 for toco conversion but I'm still receiving a syntax error